# Enable the input form type based check box input using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to Enable or Disable the input type based on the Check or Uncheck using the Java Script.

I'm using the following code..

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--

function enable_text(status)
{
status=!status; 
document.f1.other_text.disabled = status;
}
//-->
</script>


<body onload="enable_text(false)";>

<form name="f1" method="post">
<input type="checkbox"  onclick="enable_text(this.checked)" ><br>
Name
<input type="text" name="other_text">
</form>

</body>
```

But now my requirement is every input type will have corresponding Check box.

If I select one check box only corresponding input should activate.

Can anyone help for this requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--

function enable_text(status,inputName)
{
if(!inputName) {
    var inputs = document.f1.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i in inputs) {
        var input = inputs[i];
        if(input.type == 'text')
            input.disabled = true;
    }
    return;
}
status=!status; 
document.f1[inputName].disabled = status;

}
//-->
</script>


<body onload="enable_text(false)";>

<form name="f1" method="post">
<input type="checkbox"  onclick="enable_text(this.checked,'other_text')" ><br>


 Name
    <input type="text" name="other_text">
 <input type="checkbox"  onclick="enable_text(this.checked,'other_text1')" ><br>
    Name
    <input type="text" name="other_text1">
    </form>

    </body>
```

Comment: Looks Good. But it is working only for input type text. Can  you help me for activating for other inputs also.

Comment: change this input.type == 'text' to work with other types on load like this ['text', 'select'].indexOf(input.type )   > -1

Comment: But on loading it showing Enable. Once we check it and done the Uncheck  it is showing Disable.

Comment: Happy to help :). still have any issues.

Comment: :-) Actually here the requirement is we have around 20 inputs to be entered to database globally. But some may not have all the data to enter. So first we have to display which are all the fields we have option to enter and then give option to them to select which are all they can enter once they select the option & give continue, then we should give the option to them to enter those fields which they are selected in previous page.

Comment: then on load maintain an array which are need to be disable and do accordingly or maintain a separate property in input to disable which are need to be disbaled at first time